# partition PostgreSQL table based on geometry column

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-9.1

Here is the table with geometry field :

```
         Table "public.regions"
  Column   |         Type          |
-----------+-----------------------+-
 id        | integer               | 
 parent_id | integer               |
 level     | integer               |
 name      | character varying(55) |
 location  | geometry              |
```

I have stored the geometry for all continents, countries , states and cities. Since it is a huge table I need to partition the table based on top level location ( i.e continent) to improve the performance .

How can I partition my existing table based on geometry(continent) ? Is it good enough to create inheritance tables named asia, europe, australia ... and insert rows in those tables based on queries with contains ? Will that improve the performance of my queries?

For eg. I am trying to run queries like :

> 11.562424 48.148679 is some point in Munich
>
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id, name,level  FROM regions WHERE
> Contains((location),(GeomFromText('Point(11.562424 48.148679)')));

This is taking around 500 ms with PG in my computer whereas the same query is taking around 200ms in Oracle.

Comment: Have you created an index? I.e. `CREATE INDEX regions_location_idx ON "public.regions" USING gist (location);`

Comment: @MikeToews Yes I did, this is not making it much faster ...

Comment: I'm not sure how much partitioning by geometry would really help performance wise...bounding boxes are relatively quick if you have that index right.  Would seem to add more work to set up the partition than it would help your queries.  Can you give an example of a query you would run on this table?  I'm assuming you have a point and are trying to locate it in this public.regions table as fast as possible.  Does public.regions self join to itself to get different levels with each level having it's own polygon?  level,location index may help

Comment: @Twelfth Yes, right now I am trying to locate a point in regions table as fast as possible . Example query is `SELECT id, name,level FROM regions WHERE Contains((location),(GeomFromText('Point(11.562424 48.148679)')));`

Comment: Try using ST_contains for the pg query...might perform better there.  Could you give the explain plan results for the query above?...just to make sure the index is being used properly, and I suspect you can expand your index to make it more efficient.  Table partition by continent would be better handled by extracting the country code using the lat/lon and inserting that country code into your table and creating your index on that.

Comment: Second thought...I assume your table returns multiple results for a single point as it should be located in several different levels (country,province,city?).  You can narrow what you are searching down to the lowest level (city?  fewer records to do the st_contains on the faster it will run) and then use that record to build out the parent relations above it (much faster than st_contains as you are joining on an integer).

Comment: actually partioning the table has helped a lot. I am now able to run the same query twice as fast .

Comment: @PrabeshShrestha How could you partition the region table according to continent ?